# not send PUT Request to server in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want to send `PUT` Request in Angular to server .

i use this method :

```
public Update(item: TEditModel, id, url: string): Observable<ServerResponse<TEditModel>> {
    return this.httpClient.put<ServerResponse<TEditModel>>(this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + `${url}/${id}`, item);
}
```

but when i send request in `Network` tab in browser it show this error :

> (failed)net::ERR_FAILED

i have this problem with `Delete` Request .

but when i send a `POST` Request its worked good .

**Whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

[image]

Comment: We can't see much with what you posted, but it appears the endpoint is a GET endpoint.

Comment: @AustinTFrench this error from server ?

Comment: Yes, your backend method needs to allow GET. In WebApi usually the decorator will be either `[Get]` or `[HttpGet]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: (or PUT, Post, Delete etc)

Answer (score 1):

The API has not been set up to allow PUT requests.

See `Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE` in the response headers.

Comment: this problem  from server ?

Comment: Yes it is. I needs to be set up to allow PUT requests.